# Microsoft AMP for C++ with Dr Dobbs example?

Tags: c++, windows

I am trying to figure out the complete code as explained at:

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/microsofts-c-amp-unveiled/231600761?pgno=2

I am trying to find out how to generate the complete code examples with of Simple C++ AMP Version? How do I define the grid object? Which header do I need to use direct3d? It seems my Visual Studio 2012 flags these as undefined.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen `restrict(direct3d)` before.  I suspect it's supposed to be `restrict(amp)`.

You'll also need to `#include <amp.h>`